# Who is responsible for deciding if it is first request then if yes fill the route and fetch the route data from the route table in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When a client makes request who determines if the request is first request or not,if it is first  request fills the route and goes  to route table and fetching the  route data

Answer (score 1):

The application does. It probably defines an global variable in its own memory space, which it sets during the very first request, to a value that it recognizes during subsequent requests as an indicator to not consider those other requests also first. That's a trivial concept, actually.